# How to stop the Knob movement while moving cursor?

Tags: jquery, css, slider, jquery-knob

In my app, user(student) logins to application by just sliding the `knob` to right side and `CLICKS`, user's status switches from `absent` to `present`. It works fine on `tablets`. But using `laptops/desktops`,when student moves knob to right side with cursor, it gets `attach` with cursor, i mean if user moves cursor back to left side, knob moves too, without clicking on it. I want to fix that problem in the sense that when user move the knob right and clicks, it should marks present and automatically shift to its previous (left)position, rather than to chase the cursor!

**Code**

```
$(function() {
    var e = 2;
    $(".slider").each(function() {

        function u() {
            o.css({
                "-webkit-transform": "translateZ(0)",
                "-webkit-transition": "opacity 0.25s",
                "-webkit-animation": "textani 2s linear infinite forwards",
                opacity: 1
            })
        }

        function a() {
            o.css({
                "-webkit-transition": "none",
                "-webkit-animation": "none"
            })
        }

        function f(e) {
            i.css({
                "-webkit-transition": "none"
            });
            t = e
        }

        function l(n) {
            var r = Math.max(n - t, 0);
            if (r + i.width() > s.width()) {
                r = s.width() - i.width() - e * 2
            }
            var f = Math.max(80 - r, 0) / 80;
            if (f > 0) {
                a()
            } else {
                u()
            }
            i.css({
                left: r + e
            });
            o.css({
                opacity: f
            });
        }


        function c(t) {

            function o() {
                i.css({
                    "-webkit-transform": "translateZ(0)",
                    "-webkit-transition": "left 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.1, 0.7, 1.5)",
                    left: e
                });
                u();
            }

            var n = parseInt(i.css("left")) / (s.width() - i.width() + e);
            if (n > .95) {
                changeStatus();

                //  var a = r.attr("href");
                //  window.location = a;
                setTimeout(o, 250)
            } else {
                o()
            }
        }

        var t, n;
        var r = $(this);
        var i = $(this).children(".knob");
        var s = $(this).children(".track");
        var o = $(this).children(".text");
        i.bind("touchstart", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            oev = e.originalEvent;
            f(oev.touches[0].pageX);
        });
        i.bind("touchmove", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            oev = e.originalEvent;
            l(oev.touches[0].pageX);
        });
        i.bind("touchend", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            oev = e.originalEvent;
            c(0);
        });
        i.bind("mousedown", function(e) {
            f(e.screenX);
            $(document).bind("mousemove.knob", function(e) {
                l(e.screenX);
                return false;
            });
            $(document).bind("mouseup.knob", function(e) {
                c(0);

            });
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: you've bound mousedown, but not mouseup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added a new line of code that just unbound the mouseover event and its working fine :

```
i.bind("mousedown", function(e) {
            f(e.screenX);
            $(document).bind("mousemove.knob", function(e) {
                l(e.screenX);
                return false;
            });
            $(document).bind("mouseup.knob", function(e) {
                $(document).unbind("mousemove.knob");  //   this line
                c(0);
                $(document).unbind(".knob");   
             });
            return false;
        });
```